# "cannot read property 0 of undefined" in 2d array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Does anyone know why this gives an error? I've been trying at it way too long and I can't seem to figure it out. It errors with "cannot read property 0 of undefined", but it is clearly defined. (or so I think)

```
var categorySix = [["test"]["test2"],["testing"]["one"],["two"]["three"]];
document.write(categorySix[0][0]);
```

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer as accepted if your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var categorySix = [["test","test2"],["testing","one"],["two","three"]];
```

Your syntax is off.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your 2D array wrong.

Try this :

```
var categorySix = [["test","test2"],["testing","one"],["two","three"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly creating the array.

I believe it should be

```
var categorySix = [["test","test2"],["testing","one"],["two","three"]];
document.write(categorySix[0][0]);
```

As per [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)